# Find em duas collections usando aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Preciso realizar um find em duas collections no mongodb usando o aggregation e colocar os resultados em um unico array.

Estou tentado fazer da seguinte forma, mas não funciona.

Tenho a collection Visita e Oportunidades e quero sumarizar a quantidade de registros de cada usuário. Tenho em ambas as collections a variável id_user que armazena o id do usuário que a cadastrou.

```
 Visita.aggregate([  
                          {  
                            "$match": {$and: [{Active: true}, {Root: true}]}
                          },
                          {
                            "$group": { _id: "$_idUser", totalVisita: {   $sum:1} }   
                          },  
                          OpportunityEY.aggregate([  
                            {  
                              "$group": { _id: "$_idUser", totalOpp: {   $sum:1} }   
                            },  
                          ])  
                        ]).exec(function(err, result){  
                          var managers = new Array();  
                          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {  
                            var manager = new Manager();  
                            manager._id = (result[i]._id);  
                            manager.totalVisit =   result[i].totalVisita;  
                            manager.totalOpp = result[i].totalOpp;  
                            managers.push(manager);
```

No entanto ele pega apenas as informações referentes a oportunidade.

```
{_id: 1234567898765432345678, totalOpp: '2', totalVisita: "undefined"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MongoDB não da suporte, ate onde eu sei, para utilizar o framework aggregate em mais de uma collection, como também não da suporte para find, findOne e nenhum tipo de operação que não seja em uma unica collection.

**Update 3.2**

O MongoDB em sua versão 3.2 adicionou o suporte ao LeftOutJoin utilizando o novo operador $lookup no framework aggregate.

Você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira.

```
$lookup: {
    from: 'OpportunityEY',
    localField: '_idUser',
    foreignKey: '_idUser,
    as: 'opportunity_docs'
}
```

O que este operador vai fazer é, pegar todos os documentos da collection OpportunityEY onde o valor do campo _idUser seja igual ao valor _idUser do documento que esta sendo processado pelo aggregate e adicionar estes documentos como um array nomeado como opportunity_docs no documento que esta sendo processado.
Se você precisa pode utilizar o $unwind depois do $lookup e depois o $group para conseguir o grupo de dados que deseja.

Para mais informações sobre Join no MongoDB 3.2
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Para mais informações sobre o novo operador $lookup
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/